# VBA - how to use google form on IE.navigate with process in the background

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, webforms

I'm currently using the following code to open an IE instance and navigate a complete-with-answers google form link. By accessing this link, the google form is immediately answered by the "entry.1102259784=XXXX" strings.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE As Object

    Call Usernames

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Silent = True

    IE.Navigate Cells(7, 1)

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Its quite simple and works well (hidden and fast) except for this particular instance (google forms), as the IE opens and just stands there with the "Your form has been submitted" webpage on display.

The idea is to submit information about who is opening the file and when to a google spreadsheet.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This seems to be your thing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360153/use-excel-vba-to-fill-out-and-submit-google-docs-form

Comment: That does sound about right, but would it happen in the background? It doesn't seem to have any command to hide the "CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")" unless it works that way already and I'm not well informed.